# couldnt fetch mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql

I currently working in the update function for my website using php and mysql

pic 1
[image]

when i click on the edit button, it will redirect me to the edit page to update user details.

pic2
[image]

it suppose to show the data that fetch from database in pic1 in the empty text box that i created in pic2.

But the error pop-up there (as you can see in pic2).

and here is my code to catch user details from database :

```
<?php
$test= $_GET['userId'];
    echo($test);     //check user id 
        if( isset($_GET['userId']) )
        {
            $id = $_GET['userId'];
            $catchsql = "SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE userId='$id'";
            $res= mysqli_query($con,$catchsql);     //this is line 89
            $row= mysqli_fetch_array($res);     //this is line 90
        }
```

can anyone help me with this ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your answer is right here, it expects `$res` to be an `mysqli_result` object, but instead `$res` is null. This is because the query failed. It could be due in part to the fact that `userId` is likely an integer, but you treat it like a string with `'$id'`. Try it without the apostrophe's, `$id`. Furthermore, your code is wide open to SQL injection, you should look into use `mysqli prepared statements`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy agree with sql injection handling, but including the integer in quotes will still work . Check if the userId is passed in get parameter

Comment: @vinayhudli There are environments where that may fail :)

Comment: I did check every variable , the data I assign to it was correct. @vinayhudli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you didn't close connection in your dbconnection.php.
Then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

You have not defined `$id`, you have used `$test`.

Change :

```
$catchsql = "SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE userId='$id'";
```

to

```
$catchsql = "SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE userId=".$test.";
```

Since both your `$id` & `$test` have the same values, you may just use any one.

Comment: $test is for me to check whether the userId i catch from database is correct or not, but this change makes no difference, the same error still appear. Still thank you for your help.

Comment: Since both your `$id` & `$test` have the same values, you may just use any one, in the above given syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Apply proper convertion name to variable no like $test use $id

replace `$test = $_GET['userId'];` with `$id = $_GET['userId'];`

`$id` is integer in table so no need to wrap single quote `'$id'` use `$id`

Use below code to get if any error occur or result not found

```
    $catchsql = "SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE userId = $id ";
    $res= mysqli_query($con,$catchsql);     //this is line 89
    // if you don't getting than show a error
    if(!$res){
       if($error = mysqli_error($con)){
          echo $error;
     die;
       }
       echo 'No Result Found';
    }else{

    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($res); 
   }
```